# Codeigniter . Query Duplicates the result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables.

**pre_order_details**

```
  id     pre_order_id     product_id   product_quantity
```

Here  pre_order_id and product_id are forign keys and can have duplicate values.

**Recieve_Pre_Order**

```
  id    pre_order_id  product_id quantity_recieved
```

Here pre_order_id and product_id are forgin keys and can have duplicates.

I want to give pre_order_id to and fetch all the related data .

**Here is my query**

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pre_order_details');

$this->db->join('recieve_pre_order', 'recieve_pre_order.product_id = pre_order_details.product_id');


$this->db->where('pre_order_details.pre_order_id',$pre_order_id);
return $this->db->get();
```

It returns duplicate data .Can somebody point out my mistake or even my database design .

Comment: May be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748460/codeigniter-join-repeats-returned-values

Comment: usage of group by may be of help: $this->db->group_by("pre_order_id");

Answer (score 1):

Apply DISTINCT statement in select query.
`$this->db->select('*')` use specific columns

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT(pre_order_id),other column name);
```